# Update one value of data when other change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have component for generating form inputs from Vue.js data. Live version [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/MoriaCat/gp2gm3mn/1/). My data structure looks like this:

```
  data: {
    providerData: {
        archive_cost: {
            legend: 'Warehouse cost',
            fields: {
                monthly_room: {
                    label: 'Monthly cost of room',
                    value: '200',
                    unit: '$'
                },
                monthly_maintance: {
                    label: 'Monthly maintenance cost',
                    value: '10',
                    unit: '$'
                },
                summary: {
                    label: 'Summary cost',
                    value: '',
                    unit: '$',
                    disabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
},
```

The value of summary needs to be calculated as sum of monthly_room and monthly_maintenance. How do I do this? I don't want to use computed values because this form has about 20 values of this kind which will need to be passed to component and treated separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch an array of values that change the `summary.value` when updated. For example:

```
watch: {
    '[providerData.archive_cost.fields.monthly_room.value, \
    providerData.archive_cost.fields.monthly_maintance.value]': function() {
        this.providerData.archive_cost.fields.summary.value = 
            parseInt(this.providerData.archive_cost.fields.monthly_room.value) + 
            parseInt(this.providerData.archive_cost.fields.monthly_maintance.value);
    }
},
```

[Here is a fork of the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/07gzge0e/) with the change.